# Is there a way that allows us to queue multiple grpc requests?

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

So I wanted to send in multiple requests to my grpc server so that I can test out the behaviour of the server when multiple requests come in at almost the same time. I need to know that it correctly processes all the requests and at the end it leaves the system in a consistent state.

These multiple requests have slightly different messages as well. Now when I try to do it with bloomRPC, I am unable to send the next request in time because by the time I send it the first one is almost completed. When I send in the 3rd request, the first one is completed and is out of the system.

So, I wanted to know that is there any tool/method which allows us to send in multiple requests to a grpc server?

Comment: Perhaps [`ghz`](https://ghz.sh/) a "gRPC benchmarking and load-testing tool"

Comment: But I wanted to make different requests with different data as after the first request is processed, all the others fail because they are trying to do the same operation

Comment: Given that you're asking this on a programming website: can't you just write your own tiny executable that spins up 3 goroutines to make each request?